# GWT deploy on Jetty Server: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No such servlet: eventServiceImpl

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, jetty, gwt-eventservice

I want to deploy my GWT project to a jetty server, but if I put the war file into the webapps folder I get "HTTP ERROR: 503  - Service Unavailable". I checked the log file and it shows this exception:

```
2013-11-17 16:31:40.604:INFO:oejsl.ELContextCleaner:Scanner-0: javax.el.BeanELResolver purged
2013-11-17 16:31:40.604:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Scanner-0: Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@626baa8f{/VerboteneInsel,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-43055-VerboteneInsel.war-_VerboteneInsel-any-/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{/VerboteneInsel.war}
2013-11-17 16:31:43.544:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Scanner-0: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1edb9062{/verboteneinsel,file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-43055-verboteneinsel.war-_verboteneinsel-any-/webapp/,STARTING}{/verboteneinsel.war}
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.addBean(ContainerLifeCycle.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.addBean(ContainerLifeCycle.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.updateBeans(ContainerLifeCycle.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.setHandlers(HandlerCollection.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.setHandlers(ContextHandlerCollection.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.addHandler(HandlerCollection.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardDeployer.processBinding(StandardDeployer.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:329)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No such servlet: eventServiceImpl
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.updateMappings(ServletHandler.java:1328)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.setServletMappings(ServletHandler.java:1421)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.addServletMapping(ServletHandler.java:910)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor.addServletMapping(StandardDescriptorProcessor.java:1221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor.visitServletMapping(StandardDescriptorProcessor.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.addBean(ContainerLifeCycle.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.addBean(ContainerLifeCycle.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.updateBeans(ContainerLifeCycle.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.setHandlers(HandlerCollection.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.setHandlers(ContextHandlerCollection.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.addHandler(HandlerCollection.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardDeployer.processBinding(StandardDeployer.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:329)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

I assume it is caused by the external servlet I have to use for the "GWT EVENT SERVICE"
This is from my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>eventServiceImpl</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>de.novanic.eventservice.service.EventServiceImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>eventServiceImpl</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/verboteneinsel/gwteventservice</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

If I run my project local with the developement mode via GWT everything works fine...

Comment: Is the gwt-eventservice JAR in your WEB-INF/lib ?

Comment: @ThomasBroyer Yes. It is. Its also in the "build path" But it is called "gwteventservice-1.2.1" is that an issue?

Comment: BTW: I am trying to run it on jetty 9